# groups and owners with ftp

Tags: linux, ftp, groups

When a user "U" who is part of group "G" uploads a new file to the server with ftp , the permissions are set as U:U instead of U:G . I know the user is also part of his own group called "U" but how do I have them upload a file with the group "G". I don't see anyhthing in any FTP software.
Thanks

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/q/93894/984

Comment: and: http://serverfault.com/questions/184548/ftp-and-apache-permission-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you do this when you want all files in a directory to be owned by a certain group.  To make this happen set the SETGID bit on the directory `chmod g+s`.  Then any file created in that directory will belong to the group that is associated ith the parent directory.