# What is a safe alternative to wildcards in /etc/sudoers?

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, sudo, user-permissions

In the `/etc/sudoers` file on my Red Hat server, I have this line:

```
%webdevgroup ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod * /home/http/*
```

This is clearly a bad idea, since someone could do something like this:

```
sudo /bin/chmod 777 /home/http/../../etc/sudoers
```

Is there a safer way to achieve this functionality without opening the server up to this security hole?

Comment: Why don't you create several groups and add users to a certain group?

Comment: Use filesystem ACLs so users don't have to run `chmod 777`.  BTW, `chmod 777` is evil, you almost certainly don't want that, if want a half-way secure system.

Comment: utrecht: That doesn't solve the problem of an untrusted user needing to run this command.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to give rights to webdevgroup on the directory /home/http/*

ACL is a good option, but you can also have a look at setgid : [What's the purpose of setgid directory?](https://serverfault.com/questions/93894/whats-the-purpose-of-setgid-directory)